Hide Nav and footer while user is logged in ASP.NET Core
@{
    Layout = null;
}

The above code hides the nav and footer and remove the whole css.
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

If I am using this synapsis, it will not show the nav and footer.
Could anybody will give me a solution for this problem?
I need to show the navigation bar and footer after the login or sign. If I am in the login and signup page it won't.

You should work with different layouts. 1 layout for anonymous such as login, signup page. Another layout for the page that only accessed after user sign in.

It can lead to code duplication, maintenance issues, and potential inconsistencies.

Would say this is "opinion-based",  I can also say that when you handle scenarios for anonymous and login users in layout, this increases the complexity, extensibility, and maintainability. If you worry about the code duplication stuff, you can build the component section and render it as a partial view. Also, with the mentioned two layouts, I don't see the mentioned problems, unless you said that you have more than 2 layouts that repeat the same thing.

what about if( User.IsAuthenticated ) Layout = null in cshtml?

Generally, you should have different layouts for anonymous and login users (pages). This will make it easier to structure the template for the pages with different user scenarios instead of manipulating them in one layout.
With different layouts, you can render the required stylesheets, scripts, and the HTML section(s).

_LayoutAnonymous.cshtml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>


_Layout.cshtml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Nav section -->
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <!-- Footer section -->
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

On your Login and Signup page, you specify the layout used as:
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAnonymous.cshtml";
}

While for the other page that only accessible after login, you specify the layout used as:
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Reference: What is Layout View in ASP.NET MVC
